# How to wait for ACTION_DELETE action in asnyctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the following codes :

```
private class UninstallAppTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", mAppList.get(position).getPackageName(), null);

        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);
        startActivityForResult(it, 2);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Thread t = new Thread(mLoadAppLoadAndSortAppList);
        t.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When I called the UninstallAppTask, first writes "Starting" then ran doInBackground but doesn't wait for activityresult writes "Succesfull". I want to wait for close uninstall screen and then must write "Succesfull".

How can I do ?

Comment: I don't think AsyncTask is what you're looking for here. You're starting an activity on a background thread...this is bad.

Comment: well, how can I solve this solution ?